# Conflicts with routing when using default {controller}/{id} route and {controller}/{action}/{id} route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following routes setup;

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
   name: "ActionApi",
   routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional },
    constraints: null,
    handler: new WebApiMessageHandler(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration));
```

and the following controller setup;

```
public class GetFileController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

The issue I have here is that this url

```
/api/GetFile/id_is_a_string
```

returns this error;

```
<Error>
    <Message>
        No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI /api/GetFile/id_is_a_string.
    </Message>
    <MessageDetail>
        No action was found on the controller 'GetFile' that matches the name 'id_is_a_string'.
    </MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

Is there any way to get around having it not think the string parameter is actually the action name?

I know I could change my request URL to be;

```
/api/GetFile?id=id_is_a_string
```

but this routing change affects a lot of other controllers I already have set and don't really wish to go through everything to switch it up to send the request this way.

If I re-order the routes, it seems to work as it did but for my new controller which I would've ideally liked to have multiple endpoints within, I get this error;

```
ExceptionMessage=Multiple actions were found that match the request:
```

**New Controller**

```
public class GettingThingsController : ApiController
    {

        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult GetPeople()
        {
             return Ok();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult GetProducts()
        {
            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

Is there anyway of achieving what I need at all?!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to specify parameters with Regex:

```
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action:regex([a-z]{1}[a-z0-9_]+)}/{id:regex([0-9]+)}",

routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id:regex([0-9]+)}",
```

These regex works in `Route` attribute. You can test it in `RouteTable` mappings.